# The render flow in Yii

Tags: php, yii

Why is in the layouts folder we must have the column1.php ? I read the article on yii doc. It shows a diagram the View (passed as content)-> column1.php (passed as content)-> main.php.
Why the view can't pass straight to main.php ? The column1.php seems unessesary.

Comment: I guess the templated layout CSS bind to names like 'column1', 'header', ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you wish to use main.php directly, change $layout in your basecontroller (most likely Controller.php in components). Note that Yii uses column1 and column2 for placing widgets / navigation bars in CRUD code generated by Gii. If you do not use these, just delete the columnd files and change the default as described above.